# How can I share encrypted secrets through a pull request in github?

Tags: github, pull-request

I created a few encrypted secrets in a forked repo and want those secrets to carry over to the main repository when I submit a pull request.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Are you sure this is something you want? would that not defeat the purpose of having encrypted secrets ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [define encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) on a repository or, in your case, organization level, for them to be used in GitHub Actions workflows. But that would not be part of any pull request.

Encrypted secrets are generally not part of a source code base.

But you do have repository-based approach, like [ckelner/encrypted-secrets](https://github.com/ckelner/encrypted-secrets).

A better alternative is to include in your PR references to an external Vault (like [Hashicorp Vault](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault)) entries, in which said secrets are stored.